# Downloading from the internet link to the dynamically created folder. How is the path to this folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directory, webclient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpzaf.png)

I am creating a dynamic folder as seen in the design in the image. I need to download two file types of data in a link to this folder I created, but how can I download it to the folder I created?

```
        klasor = textBox1.Text;
        var yol = Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Beyza\source\" + klasor);
```

In this way, I create a folder in the 'klasor' variable.

```
    public void indirButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fileName = "C:\\Users\\Hilal Beyza\\Desktop\\projeler\\LinkProgram\\LinkProgram\\bin\\Debug\\Hilal Beyza\\yol\\webcams.mp4";
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Dosyaİndirme);
        Uri DosyaAdresi = new Uri(label3.Text);           
        web.DownloadFile(DosyaAdresi, fileName);
        
    }
```

I am giving my downloaded file a static path as above. How can I transfer this to the file I created?

Comment: You need download a file to directly dynamic folder or first does the download on static folder and transfer this file to dynamic folder?

Comment: I want to download the files directly to the folder I created dynamically. Is it possible with this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendations:** When you write a program try to name components with a logic name, example txtUri, txtFolderName, btnDownload, this facilitates understanding.

If you have a File Name and Dynamic Folder it's possible.

```
public void indirButon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string fileName = GetFileName("webcams.mp4");
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DosyaIndirme);
    Uri DosyaAdresi = new Uri(label3.Text);
    web.DownloadFile(DosyaAdresi, fileName);
}
```

This method Get File Name with new Dynamicly Folder.

```
private static string GetFileName(string fileName)
{
    string klasor = textBox1.Text;
    string directoryPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Hilal Beyza\source\", klasor);
    if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);

    return Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
}
```

If User pass complete path you need remove adapt the **directoryPath**

```
string directoryPath = Path.Combine(textBox1.Text);
```